Extending a JavaScript ES6+ class that explicitly returns an object in its constructor
I'm having issue with extending a Javascript ES6+ class that returns an object from the constructor.
Take for example:
class Base {
  constructor() {
    return {name: "base"}
  }
}

class Extension extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  saySomething() {
    console.log("What do you want me to say?")
  }
}

Creating a new instance of Extension class and calling saySomething fails with an error, because for whatever reason, which I think is related to base class returning a value in its constructor, the method saySomething does not seem to exist (in fact nothing other than just what belongs to base class) on Extension class prototype.
The major problem that has led to this base problem was me trying to create an extended PrismaClient as seen here, with client extension in NestJS, this certain way which results in other methods on the PrismaService class to not exist on the prototype chain.

function PrismaExtended() {
  type Params = ConstructorParameters<typeof PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, Prisma.LogLevel>>;
  const client = (...args: Params) =>
    new PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, Prisma.LogLevel>(...args).$extends({
      result: {
        $allModels: {
          toJSON: {
            compute(data: BaseEntity) {
              return <T extends typeof data = typeof data>() => {
                return Object.assign({}, data, {
                  sn: typeof data.sn === 'bigint' ? data.sn.toString() : data.sn,
                }) as unknown as Omit<T, 'sn'> & { sn: string };
              };
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });

  class PrismaExtended {
    constructor(...args: Params) {
      return client(...args);
    }
  }

  // Object.setPrototypeOf(PrismaExtended, PrismaClient.prototype);
  return PrismaExtended as new (...args: Params) => ReturnType<typeof client>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaExtended() implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private retries: number = 0;
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: AppLogger,
    configService: ConfigService,
  ) {
    super({
      log: pickFrom(configService, 'app.status') !== NodeEnv.PROD ? ['query'] : undefined,
      transactionOptions: { timeout: 60_000 },
    });
  }

  /**
   * Check if an error is as a result of a precodition necessary to run an
   * operation not being matched.
   *
   * @param e The error to check
   * @returns boolean
   */
  isUnmatchedPrecondition(e: unknown): e is PrismaClientKnownRequestError {
    return e instanceof PrismaClientKnownRequestError && e.code === PrismaErrorCode.UNMATCHED_PRECONDITION;
  }
}

Here the method, isUnmatchedPrecondition, and any other method added don't exist at runtime.

"which I think is related to base class returning a value in its constructor" - yes, of course it is. The result of any new Extension call is now exactly what the parent constructor returned - a plain object with one property called name, and the value base. This is not an instance of Extension. Returning anything from a constructor, is just a big anti-pattern.

Thanks for this insight @CBroe. I'm just really constrained to implement it that way: returning an object from the base constructor. The alternative approach to get it to work without this hack, seems expensive, requiring me to refactor the entire codebase. I'd love to know if there are any tweaking and hacks I can manually do on the objects prototype that can help me get it to work just this way.

you realise the initialised object has no relation with Base class or even Extension class ...strange pattern really

I also can't understand how the original Base class is supposed to work. Since it returns a plain object, it won't have the proper prototype chain, so none of its methods will work. You could return the same object from your constructor, but it will have the same problem with methods.

@Barmar That's just an illustration to generalize the actual problem, which follows after—a hack for getting prisma client extensions to work with a DI service class in NestJS. If you look through you'll notice the PrismaExtended class from the mixin returns the result of a call to client which is a PrismaClient object, and just that alone sucks all methods on the extending class PrismaService into a blackhole

Looks like PrismaExtended is making use of TypeScript features. I'm not sure what the equivalent is in vanilla JS.

@calebpitan Can you show us how new PrismaClient and its $extends method are defined? Why can't you just subclass it normally? And why don't you want to extend the class(?) their way? The solution of the problem will depend on that.

@Bergi PrismaService is defined by me. PrismaClient and the $extends method is library code not mine. The ideal, framework-agnostic way of doing this is to instantiate PrismaClient and call $extends on the instance. But it's a NestJS project, and because of Inversion of Control, I'm not in charge of instantiating PrismaService class which would have just ordinarily inherited from (class extension) PrismaClient. So I have to have first instantiated PrismaClient and $extends it before any OO inheritance on PrismaService.

"it's library code not mine" - can you link that code please?

"I'm not in charge of instantiating PrismaService class which would have just ordinarily inherited from (class extension) PrismaClient" - why does it matter that PrismaService is a class and that it does OOP inheritance? Can't you use ordinary functions for nestjs dependency injection? It shouldn't make a difference to the framework how the instantiation happens internally.

Why not just write class PrismaService { constructor(logger, configService) { return new PrismaClient({log: …, transactionOptions: …}).$extends({ result: {…}, client: {isUnmatchedPrecondition(e) { … }}}); } }?

I'm now able to get this to work by using Proxy.
Using double Proxies, one for intercepting object construction when the new keyword is used on PrismaService, and because the constructed object from the Proxy which was supposed to inherit from PrismaClient ideally, has no methods or properties of the "supposed base class" (because no inheritance of PrismaClient occured), which has already been constructed outside of the child class constructor context, I've had to keep a reference of the "supposed base class" and maintain a proxy to the constructed child class such that when any method or property is accessed on the child class instance and it's not found, it is redirected to the supposed base class whose instance I hold a reference to in the outermost proxy at the point where getClient was invoked.

function PrismaExtended() {
  type Params = ConstructorParameters<typeof PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, Prisma.LogLevel>>;
  const getClient = (...args: Params) => {
    return new PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, Prisma.LogLevel>(...args).$extends({
      result: {
        $allModels: {
          toJSON: {
            compute(data: BaseEntity) {
              return <T extends typeof data = typeof data>() => {
                return Object.assign({}, data, {
                  sn: typeof data.sn === 'bigint' ? data.sn.toString() : data.sn,
                }) as unknown as Omit<T, 'sn'> & { sn: string };
              };
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  };

  return new Proxy(class {}, {
    construct(target, args, newTarget) {
      const client = getClient(...args);
      const constructed = Reflect.construct(target, args, newTarget);

      return new Proxy(constructed, {
        get(target, key) {
          if (key in target) return target[key];
          return client[key];
        },
      });
    },
  }) as unknown as new (...args: Params) => ReturnType<typeof getClient>;
}


For now, this seems to work fine and I've not recorded any "catch" so far. But, hey, if you do notice something I'm missing, any pitfalls whatsoe'er, about this solution, do let me know.
Thanks and thanks to everyone that contributed to helping me out.
